# Ruby - no PID found in tmp/pids/thin.pid (Thin::PidFileNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, thin, padrino

I'm trying to start thin for my app but then the `pid` cannot be generated:

```
$ thin -C /var/www/project_path/current/config/myproject.testing.yml start
```

Now I can't stop it because there is no pid:

```
 $ thin -C /var/www/project_path/current/config/myproject.testing.yml stop

   /home/usr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@api/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/daemonizing.rb:131:in `send_signal': Can't stop process, no PID found in tmp/pids/thin.pid (Thin::PidFileNotFound)
```

This is the `yml` file:

```
pid: /home/usr/htdocs/testing/myproject/shared/pids/thin.pid
rackup: config.ru
log: /home/usr/htdocs/testing/myproject/shared/log/thin.log
timeout: 30
port: 1234
max_conns: 1024
chdir: /home/usr/htdocs/testing/myproject/current
max_persistent_conns: 128
environment: testing
address: 127.0.0.1
require: []

daemonize: true
```

### update:

Now I can start the server but after some `seconds` process vanish automatically; means I can't see the `pid` which was generated by starting the server after some seconds.

Answer (score 2):

```
lsof -wni tcp:1234
```

will give you the process ID

```
kill -9 PID
```

will kill the process

Comment: I'm on `Gentoo` but this command finds no process id for this port (1234) and this is the right port but I get nothing.

Comment: there is no such a process.. but commands are working if I try to look for some other ports.

Comment: Thanks, don't about others but that works well for me.

Answer (score 1):

**I had exactly the same annoying problem**

I've found that if the server crashes on startup, the pid file gets created but there is no pid in the file. Try cat'ing the log file for the server ./logs/thin.3001.log and look for errors. You could also try starting the server manually via

```
rails s -p 3000
```

and see if there are any errors thrown.

Good luck

Chris

Comment: Doesn't this start webrick instead of thin?

Comment: If you have thin installed as a gem it uses that.

Comment: have same problem - always check all you controllers for errors. error can be in some method what you not use, and this work on development mode, but it's broke all work on production)